# How use Roslyn in osx?

Tags: macos, sublimetext3, roslyn, omnisharp

I have installed ASP vNext in OSX yosemite:

https://omnisharp-sublime.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Then try to use roslyn, but not found how:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn ": "1.0.0-beta3"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "aspnet50": {
            "System.Runtime": ""
        }
    }
}

Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn  1.0.0-beta3
```

So, I wonder if this is possible, and how.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible, omnisharp-roslyn itself uses Roslyn!

Try looking through the build script here https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/blob/master/build.sh